# MariaDBで、innodb_buffer_pool_sizeを増やすと、エラーになる

Tags: mysql, mariadb

参考サイトなどを見つつ、いろいろ試行錯誤しているのですが、どうしてもinnodb_buffer_pool_sizeを増やすことができません。

グローバルバッファを増やすために、スレッドバッファを減らしてみたりしているのですが、innodb_buffer_pool_sizeを3GBを超えると、DBを再起動できなくなります。

max_connectionsなどを50くらいまでに減らしてみても、3GB以上に増やせません。なお、現在は、2800Mにしておりますが、2900Mまでは増加させることができました。

壁を越えられない原因として、何が考えられるでしょうか？

#### 環境

CentOS 6.7（2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64）
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.17-MariaDB, for Linux (i686) using readline 5.1
下記からyumでインストール
http://yum.mariadb.org/10.0.17/centos6-x86

さくらVPS 
メモリ 8 GB
ディスク    SSD 200 GB
CPU 6コア

#### 設定の参考URL

http://sawara.me/mysql/1428/
https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/optimize-my-cnf-with-mariadb.352131/

#### 実際の設定ファイル

※必要そうな部分のみ抜き出しています。

```
server.cnf
    innodb_buffer_pool_size=2800M
    innodb_log_file_size=1024M
    innodb_log_buffer_size=64MB
    key_buffer_size=16M
    join_buffer_size=256K
    max_allowed_packet=10M
    read_buffer_size=256K
    read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
    sort_buffer_size=256K
    query_cache_limit=16M
    query_cache_size=256M
    query_cache_type=1
    max_connections=80
    max_heap_table_size=32M
    tmp_table_size=32M
    table_open_cache=4096
    wait_timeout=60
```

#### mysql.logのエラー

```
[ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 131006464 bytes)
[ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 98254848 bytes)
[ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 73678848 bytes)
[ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 55246848 bytes)
[ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 41435136 bytes)
[ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 31064064 bytes)
[ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 23298048 bytes)
[ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
[ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
[ERROR] Aria engine is not enabled or did not start. The Aria engine must be enabled to continue as mysqld was configured with --with-aria-tmp-tables
[ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: OSの環境と、MariaDBのインストール方法(バイナリパッケージならパッケージのファイル名)を質問を編集して記載してください。どちらかかまたは両方が32bit(x86)になってませんか

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。DBの方が32bitでした…。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.17-MariaDB, for Linux (i686) using readline 5.1

とi686(32bit)版を使っているので4GBまでしか扱えません。